# Drools Exception executing consequence for rule "XXX" access denied

Tags: java, drools

I'm having some problems executing some rules in drools. The code runs fine when executing the javafx application via intelijj but it fails when running via java webStart (jnlp).
The error is the following:

Exception executing consequence for rule "Person DOB or TIN FATCA" in defaultpkg: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects")
    at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1083)

.....

The rules for the error are kind of random, it is not always the same rule that fails.
The rule in this case is:

```
rule "Person DOB or TIN FATCA"
when
    tr : TaxReturn( taxAuthority != Country.ZA)
    fi : FinancialInstitution ( ) from tr.financialInstitution
    ar : AccountReport ( accountHolderType == AccountHolderType.Individual ) from fi.accountReport
    ah : AccountHolder ( ) from ar.accountHolder
    pe : Person ( (birthDate == null || birthDate.toString().isEmpty()) && taxIdentification.isEmpty() ) from ah.individual
then
    Message msg = new Message (ar.getAccountHolderType().toString(),"E","EIAR001",pe.getIndex(),"birthDate", pe.getIndex());
    trData.addMessage(msg.getIndex() +"_"+ msg.getField(), msg);
    msg = new Message (ar.getAccountHolderType().toString(),"E","EIAR012",pe.getIndex(),"idNumber", pe.getIndex());
    trData.addMessage(msg.getIndex() +"_"+ msg.getField(), msg);
    msg = new Message (ar.getAccountHolderType().toString(),"E","EIAR012",pe.getIndex(),"idType", pe.getIndex());
    trData.addMessage(msg.getIndex() +"_"+ msg.getField(), msg);
    msg = new Message (ar.getAccountHolderType().toString(),"E","EIAR012",pe.getIndex(),"idCountry", pe.getIndex());
    trData.addMessage(msg.getIndex() +"_"+ msg.getField(), msg);
end
```

Also, the error only occurs in some conditions, with different objects filled in.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was:

In our Message class we have two methods that were throwing new NotImplementedException.
This wasn't supported so we had to change the exception being throw to UnsupportedOperationException.
Hope this can help anyone with similar problems.